# Creating a texture to fake transparency

Tags: texturing

*Disclaimer - I'm a developer and very new to Blender -*

I'm trying to render a complex .dae file (a car) with iOS SceneKit and I'm trying to cut some corners with transparency.

Right now in order to fit the car into the app, we needed to gut the insides of the car, so our headlights have nothing inside them, it's just glass.

I'd like to create a texture of the inside of a headlight, with none of the the actual geometry, and map it to the headlight, so it appears like everything is there. I have high resolution stills of the car at many angles, I still have the complete car model with all the headlight geometry intact. Is there a way to create and map that texture around/inside the headlights to fool the user into thinking it's all there?

I used something similar by mapping a 360 image to the inside of a sphere but this is different, and I don't have a 360 style image this time.